# Image is not displaying when using image loader android

Tags: android, lazylist

I am using image loader to display image and text from json parsing. text is displaying but image is not displaying. No error but it's displaying default icon. anyone please help me why image is not displaying. My code is as follows:

```
 public class GridAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Persons> {
 ArrayList<Persons> personList;
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
 int Resource;
 ViewHolder viewHolder;
 ImageLoader imageLoader; // declared image laoder

 public GridAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Persons> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    personList = objects;
    }
   @Override
  public int getCount() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
return super.getCount();
  }
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
View v= convertView;
 imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getContext()); // since thrown null pointer exception when i   declared this, it's not declaring null pointer exception but image is not displaying, default icon   set in ImageLoader is displaying..

if(v==null){
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(Resource, null);
    viewHolder.tvName=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvname);
    viewHolder.imageview=(ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    v.setTag(viewHolder);


}
else{
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    }
   viewHolder.tvName.setText(personList.get(position).getName());
  imageLoader.DisplayImage(personList.get(position).getImage(),viewHolder.imageview);// this is not working..
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return v;
  }
static class ViewHolder {
public ImageView imageview;
public TextView tvName;


  }

}
```

***Note:***

if I use this,

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {
        ImageView bmImage;

```
    public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mIcon11;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

}
```

and set in imageview as

```
new DownloadImageTask(holder.imageview).execute(actorList.get(position).getImage());
```

it's working.. but everytime when I scroll down and move up, image gets downloaded. I need to display in cache. so I used image loader. But it's not displaying images.

Comment: check image url may be wrong or check net permission in your project

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar i gave permissions. please check my edit.

Comment: Try `imageLoader  = ImageLoader.getInstance(); imageLoader.init();` and put this on the constructor of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest you to use ION library for loading images like this. With that library it takes only this piece of code to download image from URL asynchronously:

```
        String url = datamap.get(image1);
        Ion.with(holder.userImage).placeholder(R.drawable.new_loading)
                .error(R.drawable.loading_animation).load(url);
```

Comment: i used this too.. still image is not displaying